# Running Ubuntu on a Notebook Computer off of the SD Card slot

Tags: boot, sd-card

I don't feel like upgrading my hard drive or splitting off a partition on my existing hard drive. That said, it has a SD card slot, and I'm thinking of installing onto that partition and boot off of it instead whenever I feel like it. Since I have a desktop tower, the notebook computer is mainly served as a machine in which I edit software code being hosted online somewhere.

Would a 128 GB SD card work well enough from your experiences or stories you've heard? What about booting from the SD card? I've searched on Google and saw that the speed may be slower than even the slower magnetic HDDs.

Comment: You won't be very happy with running Ubuntu from a normal SD card, especially when defining a swap partition on that. And the card won't live for a long time because of the heavy write load. Better get a cheap external USB HDD or SDD (best with USB3).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I think I'm better off using my soon-to-be old external hard drive for that purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you would do is install the file system itself onto the SD card, and install grub onto the root of your main drive.  Or, you could go in your BIOS and set it so that the SD card boots first.  Then you would install grub on the card, too.